# How to setup reverse proxy with caddy and vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, reverse-proxy, caddy

I want to use a reverse proxy for my SPA web app. I am using Vue with webpack. Behind reverse proxy of web app I get the error "app.6b786574.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" due to being behind reverse proxy.

I have added the rewrite config exactly as given per the Vue documents for vue Router (Copy, paste caddy section into Caddyfile). Also added the caveat.

I also tried to set in vue.config.js the publicPath to '/', however that is not a good habit, but had to give it a try.

I have also tried with transparent option of caddy config. No success so far.

Or for example added the  But I believe that should not be required.

The current Caddyfile looks as follows:

```
    :443 {
        proxy / localhost:8081 {
            transparent
        }
        rewrite {
            regexp .*
            to {path} /
        }
    }
```

my vue.config.js:

```
    module.exports = {
      transpileDependencies: ['vue-octicon'],
      configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map'
      },
      devServer: {
        port: 8081,
        proxy: {
          '^/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080',
            ws: true,
            changeOrigin: true
          },
          '^/oauth': {
            target: 'http://localhost:9090'
          },
          '^/me': {
            target: 'http://localhost:9090',
            changeOrigin: true,
            ws: true
          },
          '^/product/product': {
            target: 'http://localhost:9200',
            changeOrigin: true,
            ws: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <base href="/" />
        <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
        <title>front-end</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <noscript>
          <strong>We're sorry but front-end doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
        </noscript>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

vue router, I have temporary disabled, but did not help either:

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import store from './store'
    import Router from 'vue-router'
    // some component imports

    Vue.use(Router)

    const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
      if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
        next()
        return
      }
      next('/')
    }

    export default new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      base: process.env.BASE_URL,
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          name: 'home',
          component: Home
        },
        {
          path: '/negotiation',
          beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
          // component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "negotiation" */ './views/Negotiation.vue')
          component: Negotiation
        },
        {
          path: '/marketplace',
          component: MarketPlace,
          children: [
        {
          path: '',
          component: Search
        },
        {
          path: 'add-api',
          component: AddAPI
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/user',
      name: 'user',
      beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
      component: User
      // component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ './views/User.vue')
    },
    { path: '*', component: Home }
  ]
})
```

Expected is simply to see the website. No webpack-ish errors due being behind reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the issue was with my application configuration, not the reverse proxy it self.

When using **transparent**, various information is forwarded. According to the [Caddy docs](https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy) transparent is shorthand for various upstream headers.

However, my application had to be aware of that. This is doable (using yml config) as follows by adding this to the configuration:

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
  tomcat:
    remote-ip-header: X-Forwarded-For
    protocol-header: X-Forwarded-Proto
    internal-proxies: 192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
    protocol-header-https-value: https
```

[Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html):